# Do lower MediaWiki page revision IDs always mean earlier edits?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

In general it seems true, at least for a single page, that lower revision IDs for Mediawiki page histories mean an earlier edit time. Is this true in General? Are there ever exceptions? How does revision ID minting work?

I am trying attempting trying to write a function with Pywikipedia, that will give the Page text as a of an arbitrary timestamp. It would just be more optimized to sort based on Revision ID, rather than making a dict of revision IDs timestamps, and then sorting the timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer for this on IRC thanks to user:halfak. The answer is that there is no guarantee for at least two reasons.

1. If pages are imported from a secondary wiki, then timestamps can be unrelated. And
2. If two edits occur within the same second, they will not be properly ordered, which happens sometimes.